# how to display a single result ? Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am unable to display the items called in my show function.
Anyone know why nothing is showing?

The Route :

```php
$router->get('/contrats/{id}', [
    'as' => 'contrats.show', 'uses' => 'ContratController@show'
]);
```

My public function show() :

```php
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(Contrat $contrat)
{
    return view('show', compact('contrat'));
}
```

The View part :

```xml
<p><strong>Contrat n° :</strong> {{ $contrat->id }}</p>
<hr>
<p><strong>Type d'énergie :</strong> {{ $contrat->enrgy }}</p>
<hr>
<p><strong>Numéro gsrn :</strong> {{ $contrat->gsrn }}</p>
<hr>
<p><strong>Durée du contrat : {{ $contrat->duration }} mois</strong></p>
<hr>
<p><strong>Code promotionnel utilisé :</strong> {{ $contrat->codePromo }}</p>
```

[the Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShdGw.png)

Comment: can you share the output from a dd please `{{dd( $contrat->gsrn)}}`

Answer (score 2):

I think the route should be

```php
$router->get('/contrats/{contrat}', [...])
```

for route model binding to work.

---

Another possibility is to manually query the model.

```
$router->get('/contrats/{id}', [...])
```

```
public function show($id)
{
    $contrat = Contrat::findOrFail($id);

    return view('show', compact('contrat'));    
}
```

This seems to be the approach used in [the official Lumen framework documentation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#basic-controllers)

Comment: if a change like this i have this error : Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\ContratController::show() must be an instance of App\Models\Contrat, string given, called in C:\Users\Cédric\Desktop\lumen\lumen_REST\client\vendor\illuminate\container\BoundMethod.php on line 36

Comment: My bad. I think that only works for laravel. I don't see anything about route model binding in the lumen documentation. Perhaps you need to manually do the query in the show method inside the controller.

Comment: I added an alternative to the solution. Does that work for you?